# I wrote a major report and our client put it online. How to present it in a CV?

Tags: publications, cv

Last year I spend a few months working on a 100-page design report for a client. I was the primary writer, and it was reviewed by my supervisor and then signed off by HIS supervisor. According to them, the report is a major technical publication, but the "publication" section entails the client putting it out on their webpage as a PDF.

From the perspective of academia looking through a CV, is such a report respectable? How would I cite it?

Comment: Can you call it a white paper?

Comment: I would suggest calling that document **technical report** and list it in the corresponding section of your CV (whatever the name of that section is).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds eminently sensible to put that into your CV to me: it shows you can write articles for a technical audience, and get the articles past some kind of review process, which in some sense is a researcher's job.

There's no law on how to express it, it depends how the rest of your CV is arranged. I might adjust your "Presentations" header to be "Selected presentations and reports", and then right at the top,

> I was the **leading author** on 100-page **blah blah report** for a commercially vital client of $xyz billion dollar turnover company; *report available at www.xyz.com/*